# How do I convert from using `grep -P` to `grep -E`?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, grep, bsd

I have a script that we use on Ubuntu (Linux) and I'd like to convert it to be used on both Ubuntu (Linux) and MacOS X. `grep` on Linux is different than `grep` on FreeBSD (i.e. MacOS X); `grep` on MacOS X doesn't support the `-P` option. Unfortunately, using the `-E` option on both platforms doesn't give the same results. Consider the following code that works on Linux:

```bash
wip_scenarios=$(grep -oP "^\d+ scenarios?" log/report.log | grep -oP "\d+")
echo "\n"
echo $wip_scenarios
```

This returns a `0` on Linux. Replacing all the `-P` with `-E` makes this work on MacOS X, but on Linux, this just returns a `null` which doesn't help the rest of my script when I use conditionals like this:

```bash
if [ $wip_scenarios != 0 ];then
```

One solution is to put a flag at the front and use the appropriate option set depending on the platform, but I was hoping for a cross-platform solution. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: BTW, `[ $wip_scenarios != 0 ]` is buggy itself; needs to be `[ "$wip_scenarios" != 0 ]` -- the quotes aren't optional; leaving them off can lead to some interesting bugs depending on the exact value.

Comment: On a different note, by the way -- do you want the final `s` in `scenarios` to be optional? That's what the trailing `?` is doing; if you want to match a literal `?`, the best way to do that (IMHO) is a character class: `[[:digit:]]+ scenarios[?]`

Comment: Also, don't use `""` when you can use `''`; using `"\d"` is not the same as `'\d'`, as in double-quotes, the sequence is expanded by some shells, replaced with just `"d"`.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/grep.html re: `grep -o` also not being part of the standard.

Comment: Thanks for all your tips Charles. I _did_ want the final 's' in scenarios to be optional, so the `?` is intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the regex you gave here, this is simple: Change `\d` to `[[:digit:]]`.

Thus:

```bash
wip_scenarios=$(grep -Eo '^[[:digit:]]+ scenarios[?]' <report.log | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+')
```

---

If your script starts with `#!/bin/bash` (and thus will only ever be run with `bash`), I'd also consider skipping the dependency on the non-standard extension `grep -o`, and instead depending on bash itself to separate out the numbers you care about:

```bash
# This works with any POSIX-compliant grep, but requires that the shell be bash
wip_scenarios_re='([[:digit:]]+) scenarios[?]'
wip_scenarios_line=$(grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+ scenarios[?]' <report.log)
[[ $wip_scenarios_line =~ $wip_scenarios_re ]] && {
  wip_scenarios=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
}
```

Comment: I'm always frustrated by the difficulty in reading bash scripts. I could understand most of what you wrote, but could you translate this for me? `[[ $wip_scenarios_line =~ $wip_scenarios_re ]] && {
  wip_scenarios=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
}` Something like: "If wip_scenarios_line matches the given regexp, wip_scenarios_re, then..."? Why the `&&`? What does that mean?

Comment: It means the same thing it means in C or Java -- it's a short-circuiting boolean "and". `a && b` has the side effect of only evaluating `b` if `a` is true, so it serves double duty as a conditional, itself evaluating to a value that represents whether both commands succeeded..

Comment: Is this a common bash script idiom? I'm just curious, because while I understand it, it doesn't come across as particularly readable.

Comment: Which part? There are lots of idioms in here. That said, the things that might be surprising -- like assigning the regex to a string before running it -- are done for reasons (in that particular case, compatibility with older versions of bash back before `=~` syntax stabilized).

Comment: Oh -- you mean `&&`. Yes, that's very idiomatic, not just in bash but in POSIX shells in general. (Now, there are also related antipatterns -- folks who use `a && b || c` to mean `if a; then b; else c; fi`, for instance, are inviting bugs. Incidentally, that same practice used to be a problem back in the Python world as well, back before one-liner conditional syntax was introduced there).

Comment: @Charles What's the advantage of using `$condition && { ... }` instead of `if $condition; then ...; fi`? Isn't the if-statement more flexible? Like say you needed to add an `elif` or `else` clause, it'd require less rewriting. Or if you needed to add another `&&` condition, it'd be easier to see where the conditions end and the consequent begins.

Comment: You're absolutely right: `if` is more flexible (and harder to inadvertently misuse); the sole advantage is terseness.